# Faster version of sweep R

Tags: r, matrix

I am interested in using the sweep command to add/subtract a vector across the dimensions (rows or columns) of a matrix.

I have seen that the sweep command seems to be the fastest way to approach this--however is there a faster way anyone has come across? I don't mind dropping the code in Rcpp if necessary, but woud prefer to stay in R if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use from package `Rfast` function `eachrow`.

```
x=Rfast::matrnorm(1000,1000)

Rfast2::benchmark(a<-sweep(x,2,x[1,]),b<-Rfast::eachrow(x,x[1,],"-"),times = 10)
   milliseconds 
                                        min     mean      max
a <- sweep(x, 2, x[1, ])            30.7998 136.7322 578.4243
b <- Rfast::eachrow(x, x[1, ], "-")  3.2755   7.9140  30.7017


all.equal(a,b)
[1] TRUE
```

Unfortunately there is no a column major version yet but R handle this automatically with the base operators.